# Comparing two identical MDB tables, except one has the first column removed

Tags: c#, ms-access

So, working on an internal tool at work which compares two MDB files and lists the differences between the two. However, when testing the tool with two similar MDB's except the second has the first column removed, an exception is thrown at the following line:

```
nCompareResult = ((IComparable)leftRows[nLeftRows][nLeftSortedColumn])
                   .CompareTo(rightRows[nRightRow][nRightSortedColumn]);
```

What should that comparison be equal to considering it is trying to compare a non-null table cell to a cell that doesn't exist?

If I was not specific or overlooked something please feel free to let me know in the comments.

Comment: Why don't you just compare the column count of the table first?

Comment: That's done later on. What would comparing the column counts do?

Comment: Done later on? You comparison should be going from less specific to more specific, not the other way around. Perhaps you should include more of your code to accurately portray the situation.

Comment: I actually figured the error out in the particular code snippet I have. If someone else comments or is interested in the work-around I can post the code so it could have a more in-depth solution.